# VBA many Vlookups on filtered cells

Tags: vba, excel

I've been banging my head on this one for a while.

I have a big macro I made doing a number of operations on  a file but got stuck on doing a series of filtering and vlookups.

Here is a portion of what I got. I added comments to make it clearer.

```
 'FILTER ALL 3P VALUES IN ONE COLUMN AND ADD A VALUE IN ALL RESPECTIVE CELLS IN OTHER COLUMN
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="*3P*"
        .Offset(1).Range("AU1:AU" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

 'HERE I SELECT ALL VISIBLE FILTERED CELLS BY COUNTING IN ROW A BECAUSE THESE CELLS ARENT BLANK
        .Selection.Value = "3P PROGRAM"
        .AutoFilter
      End With

 'NOW I WANT TO FILTER ROW FOR BLANKS AND THEN FILL THIS RANGE WITH A FORMULA 
 'HERE IS THE PROBLEM

      With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=47, Criteria1:="="
        .Offset(1).Range("AU1:AU" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        .Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-38],'[WeeklyData.xlsx]Sheet1'!C8:C16,9,FALSE)"
        .AutoFilter
      End With
```

Problem is at the vlookup step. I want that range of visible filtered blank cells to get the value gotten by vlookup. Every cell should take a cell 38 columns to the left as a vlookup reference.

I cant find a way to make formula work. I would like to: 
-insert vlookup to that filtered range, 
-remove filter (Autofilter)
-Select calculated column with offset of 1 for headers and paste as special values
- carry on to do this process 5, 6 more times for blank or invalid entries in other columns.

Is there a way to do this?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Question: Why is your Vlookup Table only 1 column wide? That right there would throw an error and keep the formula from working.

Comment: @Jess-eye-ca - That's an `xlR1C1` cell range reference. It actually refers to `Sheet1'!H:P` which is 9 columns wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) over the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx). It refers to the 'data island' created at the origin point (in this case, A1).

```
With ActiveSheet
    If .AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        'Set the filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="*3P*"
        'Shift off the header row
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            'check if there are any visible cells
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                'Put 3P PROGRAM into the visible cells in column AU
                Intersect(.Columns(47), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = "3P PROGRAM"
            End If
        End With
        'remove the filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=22

        'set the formula on column AU blank cells
        Intersect(.Columns(47), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)).FormulaR1C1 = _
          "=VLOOKUP(RC[-38], '[WeeklyData.xlsx]Sheet1'!C8:C16, 9, FALSE)"

        'revert column AU within the .CurrentRegion to the values returned by the formulas
        .columns(47).cells = .columns(47).cells.value

    End With
End With
```

The second filter is replaced by using the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the [xlCellTypeBlanks property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx). The [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) isolates the cell range reference to the blank cells within column AU. You may want to make a check for blank cells before running that operation.

Comment: Thanks Jepped,this is amazing. Could you please add a line that would at the end take entire column 47/ or AU from under header to the end of the data and paste it as special values because now it contains vlookup formulas. I will nest a few of these in my big macro. Thanks! You made it so much more elegant and practical. I really appreciate comment explaining every line. Its a great learning tool.

Comment: And once again you solved in one line what I do in a couple. Thanks mate for this teaching moment. I really appreciate it.